# How to drop index with the same key_name in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I create 2 columns is unique, which syntax `show index from mytable`

in column key_name has 2 row with the same `key_name`

how can I delete both of them,

```
SQL: alter table `article_product` drop index `article_product_article_id_product_id_index`
```

ERROR

```
Can't DROP 'article_product_article_id_product_id_index'; check that column/key exists
```

Comment: you can rollback and edit migration file. then re-migrate. `php artisan migrate:rollback` and after edit the migration, `php artisan migrate`

Comment: $table->dropUnique('users_email_unique'); https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations

Comment: #staskus there are 2 key_names with the same. That syntax is wrong. Sorry